# MongoDB PyMongo - create an index and make a case insensitive search in two fields

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

Feels like hitting a brick wall, so help is really appreciated!

I got two fields in the database, both can contain various text.
From what I've read up so far, I need to create an index first, but since I got two fields and not one.. How do I search in it? Plus it has to be case insensitive.
Using MongoDB 4.4
Pymongo has it's own var for "text", as well as own create_index call, so this is correct?

```
collection.create_index([('author' , pymongo.TEXT), ('title' , pymongo.TEXT)])
```

How do I proceed from here and make a case-insensitive search for one search_string?

Comment: Can you help us by describing what 1 or 2 docs look like and pseudocode the query to produce the desired result?

Comment: A text index uses language-based rules for stemming and pluralization, is that the kind of thing you need for an author field?

Comment: If you are using Atlas, you will probably see better results for your query. There is a Python github project where the legacy text search functionality was replaced with Atlas Search: https://github.com/MarcusSorealheis/Atlas-Search-Python

Comment: It is something like a library database, millions of entries and users input one string to search for which may contain the author and some words from the title, or only some words, or only the author.. you get the idea. No need for stemming and pluralization though. I'd rather avoid using regex for this one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution features case-insensitive, stop-word sensitive lookup on both `author` and `title` fields at the same time on the special `$text` index:

```
   rc = db.foo.create_index([('author' , pymongo.TEXT), ('title' , pymongo.TEXT)])

    r = [
    {"author":"Buzz","title":"Dangferous iewhf"}
    ,{"author":"Dave","title":"Corn"}
    ,{"author":"Dave","title":"The buzz about wheat"}
    ,{"author":"Chris","title":"Not in this film"}
    ,{"author":"Herbert","title":"Dune"}
    ,{"author":"Herbert","title":"Children of Dune"}
    ]
    db.foo.insert_many(r)


    searchstring = "Dune"                                       
   
    for doc in db.foo.find({"$text": { "$search": searchstring } } ):
        print(doc)
```

For more details on exact phrases, multiple words, word exclusion, etc. see the docs here:
[MongoDB $text index features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)

Comment: Thanks! I've actually came to the same results :) though it does seem that to find results with impartial search strings there's no way around other than just using regex. So I had to implement it too in the end. Good reference for it in Python found here, if anyone would need in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018277/14641358